# C++ rendering engines to look at for learning purposes

Tags: c++, 3d, render, 3d-rendering

I'm looking for recent c++ 3D Rendering engines to use as a roadmap for my own little render engine. 
I'm in no hurry and prepared to spend a couple of years working on this, as it's mostly for learning and fun. For now I've chosen [Horde3D](http://www.horde3d.org/), as it looks relatively recent and pretty good, but before I jump in I'd like to know the advice of the good folks at stackoverflow.

In short, any good rendering engines to look at to make my own?
Preferably:

- Open source
- Well documented
- Recent
- High performance
- Multiplatform